# Implicit finite difference scheme for a non-linear PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, nonlinear-analysis, finite-difference-methods

I am trying to write a finite difference scheme to solve numerically a 2-nd order non-linear equation :

$$\boxed{\frac{\partial h}{\partial t} = A\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(h^{3}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)}$$

With following boundary conditions :

- $h(x,t=0) = 0$
- $\frac{\partial h}{\partial x} = 0 \space \mbox{for} \space \lvert {x} \rvert = \infty $

I am attempting to write an implicit scheme like this :

$$\left[\frac{h_{i}^{n+1}-h_{i}^{n}}{\delta t}\right] = A \left[\left(h_{i}^{n}\right)^{3}\left(\frac{h_{i+1}^{n+1}-2h_{i}^{n+1}+h_{i-1}^{n+1}}{(\delta x)^{2}}\right)+3\left(h_{i}^{n}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{h_{i+1}^{n+1}-h_{i}^{n+1}}{\delta x}\right)^{2}\right]$$

By noting that :
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left(h^{3}\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right) = \left(h^{3} \frac{\partial^{2}h}{\partial x^{2}} + 3h^{2}\left(\frac{\partial h}{\partial x}\right)^{2}\right)$$

How do you think I can write the matrix calculation in order to implement the problem numerically ? I am somehow disturbed by those $h_{i}^{n}$ terms...

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Since the PDE is non-linear, it is also non-linear after discretizing it. So would need to apply a Newton-Raphson method with linear system solves at each iteration.

Comment: @DanDoe Thank you for your comment : The fact is that I am looking to write this linear system with the corresponding matrix if possible ? I have never used such a method for a non-linear equation like this one so I am "stuck" after the line that I wrote in the post.

Comment: Out of the box, you cannot write this as a linear system like $B \boldsymbol h = \boldsymbol u $, since the equation is non-linear; you have something like $\boldsymbol{F} (\boldsymbol h ) = 0$. As in the Newton-Raphson method, you could linearize the system and then plug in the current state and use this to determine the next one.